# R - group_by n_distinct for summarise

Tags: r, unique, dplyr

My dataset looks like this

```
library(dyplr) 

dta = rbind(c(1,'F', 0), 
  c(1,'F', 0), 
  c(1,'F', 0), 
  c(2,'F', 1), 
  c(2,'F', 1), 
  c(3,'F', 1), 
  c(3,'F', 1), 
  c(3,'F', 1), 
  c(4,'M', 1), 
  c(4,'M', 1), 
  c(5,'M', 1), 
  c(6,'M', 0)
)

colnames(dta) <- c('id', 'sex', 'child')
dta = as.data.frame(dta)
```

So the data are long-format with **id** as personal identifier.

My problem is when I try to count the **sex** for example, 
I dont have the right count because of the repetition of the **id**.

So there is 3 females and 3 males.

but when I count I have

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(n())
```

8 and 4 - because it counted the rows and not the unique **id**

Same problem with the cross table

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(sex, child) %>% 
  summarise(n())
```

How do I indicate the unique identifier (`n_distinct`) in the count ?

Comment: You don't want to create a data set in that way. `c(1,"F",0)` is a character vector.

Comment: @Frank, sure you are right, my original dataset was really hard to `dput`, I just wanted to create a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways to do this, here's one:

```
dta %>% distinct(id) %>%
        group_by(sex) %>%
        summarise(n())
```

EDIT: After some discussion, let's test how quick varying methods work.

First, some larger data:

```
dta <- data.frame(id = rep(1:500, 30),
                  sex = rep (c("M", "F"), 750),
                  child = rep(c(1, 0, 0, 1), 375))
```

Now let's run our varying methods:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
    distinctcount = dta %>% distinct(id) %>% count(sex),
    uniquecount = dta %>% unique %>% count(sex),
    distinctsummarise = dta %>% distinct(id) %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(n()),
    uniquesummarise = dta %>% unique %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarise(n()),
    distincttally= dta %>% distinct(id) %>% group_by(sex) %>% tally
)
```

On my machine:

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     distinctcount  1.576307  1.602803  1.664385  1.630643  1.670195  2.233710   100
       uniquecount 32.391659 32.885479 33.194082 33.072485 33.244516 35.734735   100
 distinctsummarise  1.724914  1.760817  1.815123  1.792114  1.830513  2.178798   100
   uniquesummarise 32.757609 33.080933 33.490001 33.253155 33.463010 39.937194   100
     distincttally  1.618547  1.656947  1.715741  1.685554  1.731058  2.383084   100
```

We can see unique works pretty poorly on larger data, so the quickest is:

```
dta %>% distinct(id) %>% count(sex)
```

Comment: The documentation of `dplyr` says that `distinct` is just a faster (written in C++) version of `unique`. In fact they to the same job I think.

Comment: @jeremycg thanks a lot ! ... beside speed which solution is *the most esthetic* or *beautiful* ? ;)

Comment: I think my initial one was the best looking, as I think in that order and it's more explicit. If you think differently, maybe you like the others.

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
aggregate(id ~ sex, dta, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Output:

```
  sex id
1   F  3
2   M  3
```

Another alternative with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) 
count_(unique(dta), vars = "sex")
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  sex n
1   F 3
2   M 3
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT sex, COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) AS n 
      FROM dta GROUP BY sex")
```

Output:

```
  sex n
1   F 3
2   M 3
```